# Session in the model and testing it with BDD

Tags: session, cakephp, bdd

I use CakePHP and got the following validation code to check the balance for a user is greater before that user can use the funds.

```
class Investment extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
    'amount' => array(
        'rule4' => array(
            'rule' => array('greaterBalance'),
            'message' => 'Sorry, you do not have sufficient funds to make this investment.',
        )
    ),

    public function greaterBalance($check) {
    $user_id = CakeSession::read('Auth.User.id');
    $user = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.id' => $user_id)));
    $value = array_values($check);
    $amount = $value[0];        
    return ($user['User']['balance'] >= $amount);
}
```

when I run the bdd code I get the following error **Notice: Undefined index: cookie in /usr/share/cakephp/2.4.5/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/CakeSession.php line 486**

I suspect it's due to the use of session in greaterBalance.
I run the bdd using Console/cake Bdd.story as I got the plugin **sizuhiko/Bdd**
Is there a way to mock or do something to use session when using bdd?

The feature file

```
Scenario: Investor invests money in a pitch
  When I invest "500" pounds 
  Then The balance should be deducted
```

Answer (score 0):

Shells don't use cookies. They're not a browser.

Your code has because of that an architectural flaw: You should not use session data inside the model but instead pass it to the model. Pass the user data to the model in a field like user_id and use it from there. This decouples the session from the model and makes testing and use in shells a lot easier.

Further you should not access the Auth data in the session the way you do it. The right way is  to use the Auth components user() method.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed already the code to get the user id from the Controller. I asked simply as saw in CakePhp doc examples you can get the session for the Model.